# I can't access an object's properties

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-react

The next lines work fine and I can see the whole object in the console log:

```
Meteor.subscribe('projects')
var oneProject = Projects.findOne(key1);
console.log(oneProject)
```

In the console, I can see the oneProject's properties, even the `name` property.

Now with the following lines, the result is an error:

```
Meteor.subscribe('projects')
var oneProject = Projects.findOne(key1);
console.log(oneProject.name)
```

The error is: "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

This is the whole code:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Projects } from '/imports/api/projects.js';
import ProjectFormUpdate from './ProjectFormUpdate.jsx';

export default ProjectFormUpdateContainer = withTracker(({ key1 }) => {
  Meteor.subscribe('projects')
  var oneProject = Projects.findOne(key1);
  console.log(oneProject.name)
  return {
    oneProject:oneProject,
  };
})(ProjectFormUpdate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subscription in Meteor is *asynchronous*. This means the data is not always immediately available.

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  const sub = Meteor.subscribe('projects');
  if (sub.ready()){
    const oneProject = Projects.findOne(key1);
    console.log(oneProject.name);
  }
});
```

will not try to find the project until the subscription is ready.

Comment: Ok now i can put in console the "name" but it still doens't let me to pass the Project document to the component property. The error: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object at keys (<anonymous>)"

Comment: i created another question about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746047/how-to-pass-an-meteor-document-object-from-container-to-react-component